# Alternative to Java's Observable class?

Tags: java, events, observer-pattern, observable

I'm coming to Java from the C# world where the Observer pattern is implemented as a first-class language construct with the `event` keyword.

I see that Java's had the `Observable` class since the early days, but it clearly has implementation issues and doesn't seem to be widely used.  Thus far I've just been rolling-my-own implementation of the Observer pattern in my Java code but I always can't help but think there must be a better alternative to always turning out this boilerplate code.  There are the Listener classes in Swing but they don't seem appropriate for non-Swing code.

What's the recommended solution for this oh-so-common problem?  Third-party libraries are ok with me.

Comment: Why aren't listener classes appropriate for non-Swing code?

Comment: It seems like all of the EventListener derived interfaces and classes are in the Swing and AWT packages.  Since they're in a package that's responsible for UI, using them for non UI seems like a bad smell to me.  Are EventListeners used outside of these UI contexts?

Comment: Who's to stop you from deriving your own listener classes? `EventListener` and `EventObject` are both in `java.util`, they aren't bound to AWT or Swing in any way.

Comment: The `EventListener` interface is rather useless. It declares no methods.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usually the observer pattern is implemented with an ad-hoc solution when ever it's needed. When it comes to behavioral patterns it's one of the simplest: two methods to control a list of "observers," and one method that notifies the observers when something interesting happens.

The observer pattern tends to arise too infrequently outside of certain domains, and when it does arise it tends be too specific to the application domain, so generic solutions are of little value. You can see the problem with the `java.util.Observable` class: if you inherit from `Observable` you have to accept every possible kind of "observer" that may be passed to you, which likely makes no sense for your application:

- What if your object can produce two different kinds of events, and thus needs two different lists of observers?
- What if the observers may influence your object depending on the event, e.g. by being able to veto a change?

That said, [EventBus from Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained) seems to do a pretty good job of simplifying event producing and handling by taking a radically different approach.

Other [techniques based on annotations have been discussed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178700/generic-annotation-driven-event-notification-frameworks) before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm not sure about your statement about generic observer solutions being of little value, although I can see that argument applied to Java's Observer implementation.  To bring up C# again, Observer is first-class citizen in it's `event` construct which is used heavily in .NET.  I think the generic observer just has to be implemented properly, and perhaps its the case that a language construct is really needed to pull it off.

Comment: Yes, a language construct is needed. For example if you have `N` different kinds of events the class has to be augmented with `N` sets of methods for managing event listeners. But a Java language library cannot add an arbitrary number of methods to classes where it is used.

Comment: major issue we had with util.Obserable or original GoF approach is that in a large application, threading, deadlock, and performance becomes mad. we turned our app with the even bus approach

Answer (score 7):

I recommend looking into [reactive programming](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/00_Foreword.html). Java has only one implementation that I know of: [reactive4java](https://code.google.com/p/reactive4java/).

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks.  I recently started using Reactive Extensions in my C# development and it's quite impressive.

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364408/Spring-Loaded-Observer-Pattern) shows a nice implementation of the pattern using Spring Framework. You still need to define your Subject and Observer interfaces (and implementations), but Spring handles the Observer registration to Subjects through XML configuration.