# Run a task based on a trigger java

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

I want to run a task if there is a **trigger** (i.e. **Some event like new file added to directory**) in Java. Does Java have inbuilt support for this? 
If not, what third party library I can use to facilitate this?

Answer (score 1):

In Java 7 there is the Watch Service that allows a task to happen when a change or event is detected on a file or directory.

Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#overview

API documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html

Here is a quick example I've cooked up:

```
package watcher;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;

public class Watcher {

    private final FileCreatedAction action;
    private final String pathToWatchString;

    public Watcher(FileCreatedAction action, String pathToWatchString) {
        this.action = action;
        this.pathToWatchString = pathToWatchString;
    }

    public void start() throws IOException {
        FileSystem defaultFileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
        WatchService watchService = defaultFileSystem.newWatchService();
        Path pathToWatch = defaultFileSystem.getPath(pathToWatchString);
        pathToWatch.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
        while(true) {
            try {
                WatchKey key = watchService.take();
                if (key != null) {
                    for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                        if (event.kind().equals(StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE))
                        {
                            WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;
                            Path filename = ev.context();
                            Path fullFilename = pathToWatch.resolve(filename);
                            action.performAction(fullFilename);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException error) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileCreatedAction action = new FileCreatedAction() {

            @Override
            public void performAction(Path fullPath) {
                System.out.printf("Found file %s", fullPath);
            }
        };

        Watcher watcher = new Watcher(action, "/foo");
        watcher.start();
    }

}

interface FileCreatedAction {
    void performAction(Path fullPath);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the continuous looping? I mean I want to basically have a Action class and the Trigger class (with method isTriggered()) which could be a new file added and execute the action when the trigger is true.

Comment: For the trigger class look at the StandardWatchEventKinds.  The WatchService method take() avoids having to have a busy wait loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily implement your own file system tracker.
There's a nice, working example in here:

[How to watch the file system for changes in Java 7 (JDK 7)](http://java.dzone.com/news/how-watch-file-system-changes)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, what you need is a design pattern called '[Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)'. You can implement your own, without needing any inbuilt support or external frameworks.

For inbuilt support, check Java's 'util' package for '**Observer**' and **EventListener** (since Java 7) interfaces.

Also, check the following links:

1) [Generic, annotation-driven event notification frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178700/generic-annotation-driven-event-notification-frameworks)

2) [Alternative to Java's Observable class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218895/alternative-to-javas-observable-class)